# When using Python to save files, can I skip the uploading to Onedrive step and keep it in the background?

Tags: python, excel, onedrive, shutil

I am trying to use python to save files in a local directory which is linked to Onedrive.
My python script wouldn't stop running until it finishes the uploading to onedrive process, which could take a while when the file is large (>200 MB).

My question is, can I save the file to local OneDrive folder as an end to my script, and let OneDrive do the uploading job in the background, like what OneDrive usually does if you save/copy/move files in Windows?

For example, if I use shutil to copy a file between the same folders, it won't invoke the OneDrive uploading process when the script was run. Once the script is finished, OneDrive is updating the changes in the background.

```
import win32com.client as win32

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:/Users/OneDrive/my scripts/Example.xlsx")
wb.SaveAs("C:/Users/OneDrive/my scripts/files/New.xlsx")

excel.Application.Quit()
```

I skipped the manipulations to the excel file as they are not relevant.

```
import shutil


shutil.copyfile("C:/Users/OneDrive/my scripts/Example.xlsx", "C:/Users/OneDrive/my scripts/files/New.xlsx")
```

Comment: Try and save the file somewhere else, then move it with syscall

Comment: Sorry that's not an option for me at the moment

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [OneDrive will synchronize with the cloud automatically](https://www.cloudwards.net/review/onedrive/). If you're needs are time-critical, you can [force a sync](https://superuser.com/questions/1151464/how-to-force-onedrive-to-synchronize) using the %localappdata%\Microsoft\OneDrive\onedrive.exe command with the /reset option.

Comment: Please check my edit about using shutil. I am not sure I got what you are saying. I wanted my script to finish without syncing.

Comment: Just save the file to C:/Users/OneDrive/my scripts/ and run the onedrive.exe /reset command to synchronize it.